# Partial search in solr same as sql Like %que% in Drupal 6

Tags: php, search, solr, drupal-6

I am currently facing problem in `drupal 6` solr configuration. I want to implement search in drupal 6 using `apache solr` same as in `mysql` if I search Like `%que%` then it will return results
like these...

`question

questions

etc`

also I need to implement exact search.

Anybody have clue or patch for this will be very appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Lucene supports wild card queries which allow you to perform searches such as book*, which will find documents containing terms such as book, bookstore, booklet, etc. Lucene refers to this type of a query as a 'prefix query'.

Lucene also supports wild card queries which allow you to place a wild card in the middle of the query term. For instance, you could make searches like: mi*pelling. That will match both misspelling, which is the correct way to spell this word, as well as mispelling, which is a common spelling mistake.

Another wild card character that you can use is '?', a question mark. The ? will match a single character. This allows you to perform queries such as Bra?il. Such a query will match both Brasil and Brazil. Lucene refers to this type of a query as a 'wildcard query'.

Leading wildcards (e.g. *ook) are not supported by the QueryParser by default. As of Lucene 2.1, they can be enabled by calling `QueryParser.setAllowLeadingWildcard( true )` . Note that this can be an expensive operation: it requires scanning the list of tokens in the index in its entirety to look for those that match the pattern.

Reference: [Lucene wildcard search.](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneFAQ?highlight=%28leading%29|%28wildcard%29#What_wildcard_search_support_is_available_from_Lucene.3F)

Comment: Especially watch out for queries with '*' in the beginning. These can be really expensive.

Comment: I thought Solr was free. :)